# replace string between 2 dot with sed

Tags: sed

my file contain lines like that:

```
level0.1.level1.1.level1
level0.1.level1.2.level2
```

I want to replace ".x." with "{i}"

so the desired lines are like follow

```
level0.{i}.level1.{i}.level1
level0.{i}.level1.{i}.level2
```

Answer (score 1):

When we look for ".x.", meaning "." followed by any character
followed by ".", the search pattern for sed will be
"\..\.", as we need to escape the "." with "\".
Once the match is found replace it with ".{i}."
The "/g" at the end implies multiple such replacements.

```
 cat file | sed 's/\..\./.{i}./g'
```

Comment: Missed an 'i' inside {}. Thanks for the clue

Comment: Please provide a brief explanation for your code snippet

Comment: To catch all `.x.` patterns  (including those adjacent) use: `:a;sed 's/\..\./.{i}./g;ta' file`. N.B. the second `.` is the adjacents first.'

Answer (score 0):

using sed

```
sed -r 's/[.][0-9]+[.]/.{i}./g'
```

crash test

```
 echo 'level0.1.level1.2.level2'|sed -r 's/[.][0-9]+[.]/.{i}./g'
```

output

```
level0.{i}.level1.{i}.level2
```

Comment: did you tested it with file

Comment: results will be the same..command line to use sed -r 's/[.][0-9]+[.]/.{i}./g' file..:D